# Merging two held expressions into a held compound expression

Tags: evaluation, expression-manipulation

Consider

```
e1 = Hold[a = x + x; b = y + y + y];
e2 = Hold[c = a + a + b + b + b; c^2];
```

How can I obtain the following?

```
e12 = Hold[a = x + x; b = y + y + y; c = a + a + b + b + b; c^2]
```

For example,

```
e1 ~Join~ e2
```

does not work since it gives one "," sign in the middle. another attempt

```
With[{e1temp = e1, e2temp = e2}, Hold[e1temp; e2temp]]
```

gives nested `Hold` calls that at the end do not want to evaluate (and are hard to get rid off):

> ```
> Hold[Hold[a = x + x; b = y + y + y]; Hold[c = a + a + b + b + b; c^2]]]
> ```

I am amazed that such a simple thing is causing me so much pain. :)

#### Edit

My current solution.

```
merge[Hold[expr1_], Hold[expr2_]] := Hold[expr1; expr2]
merge[e1, e2]
```

> ```
> Hold[(a = x + x; b = y + y + y); (c = a + a + b + b + b; c^2)]
> ```

Comment: I have solved it by coding a special merge function: merge[Hold[expr1_],Hold[expr2_]] := Hold[expr1, expr2], though I do not really understand why it woks. anyway, I would like to know whether there are other ways (e.g. without using such a function; and yes, the construct ()& would be cheating).

Comment: another option is to convert everything to strings and the merge strings and use ToExpression to convert back. but, that I would like to avoid too...

Comment: That function from your comment gives precisely the same result as `Join`.  It should be `merge[Hold[CompoundExpression[expr1__]], 
  Hold[CompoundExpression[expr2__]]] := 
 Hold[CompoundExpression[expr1, expr2]]`.

Comment: apologies (it was a typo in the definition). please take a look at the EDIT above. it gives the right thing (though with too many ()'s). smart to put explicit CompoundExpression headers. but, as I said, the question is whether it is possible to do it wihout the merge function.

Comment: @Szabolcs I had believed that the following accomplishes what you want to do:
`e12 = Thread[Join[e1, e2]]` gives `Hold[a = x + x; b = y + y + y, c = a + a + b + b + b; c^2]`  However, as Szabolcs pointed out in a comment to the answer I had posted, it puts it as two elements in the `Hold` with the comma in between. I realized that this was the same as what zorank had meant with the `~Join~` command, so I have deleted it as an answer and moved it here to a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why you don't like your `merge` function. This is the same pattern matching approach but using `ReplaceAll`:

```
{e1, e2} /. {Hold[x_], Hold[y_]} :> Hold[x; y]
```

If you would rather avoid patterns here is one (ugly) option:

```
Block[{CompoundExpression}, (e1; e2) ~Thread~ CompoundExpression ~Thread~ Hold]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is nothing wrong with the solutions you have. If for whatever reason you'd really need to join into one `CompoundExression` instead of nesting three of them, then here are two way to achieve that:

```
CompoundExpression @@@ Join[
  Hold @@@ Hold[a = x + x; b = y + y + y],
  Hold @@@ Hold[c = a + a + b + b + b; c^2],
  2
]
```

Many functions which operate on "generalized" lists have a level argument and so does `Join`. Unfortunately it wants the heads of all levels above the one it operates to be the same which makes necessary to exchange the `CompoundExpression` by `Hold` temporarily for you example and the above a little more complicated than one would wish...

Of course pattern matching is also an options which almost always will provide a solution:

```
Replace[
 {Hold[a = x + x; b = y + y + y], Hold[c = a + a + b + b + b; c^2]},
 {Hold[CompoundExpression[cp1__]], Hold[CompoundExpression[cp2__]]} :>
   Hold[CompoundExpression[cp1, cp2]]
]
```

Comment: what does the @@@ construct mean? I've checked the documentation, but can't find it. Is it a combination of the two @ and @@?

Comment: @zorank: @@ is a shortcut for `Apply`. @@@ is a shortcut for `Apply[_,_,{1}]` that is apply at first level. You'll find details in the documentation for `Apply`...